# How can I increase the delay of a Lightning spinner?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am new to Lightning Aura Components. I have created a lightning quick action button on vf page. After the button click it will do some functionality behind. Meanwhile I am displaying a spinner on the page. I would like to increase the delay for the spinner. Can someone help me on this?

//Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.lightningAbortEmail');
        action.setParams({
            recId : component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var title = '';
            var type = '';
            var message = '';
            
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            if(state == "SUCCESS") {
                if(response.getReturnValue() == 'Aborted') {
                    component.set("v.spinner", true);
                    type = 'info';
                    message = 'Email send is already aborted';
                } else if(response.getReturnValue() == 'Completed') {
                    component.set("v.spinner", false);
                    type = 'error';
                    message = 'Email send is completed and can\t be aborted';
                } else if(response.getReturnValue() == 'true') {
                    component.set("v.spinner",false);
                    type = 'success';
                    message = 'Email send aborted successfully';
                }
            }
            else {
                component.set("v.spinner",false);
                type = 'error';
                message = '';
            }
            window.setTimeout(
                $A.getCallback(function() {
                    component.set("v.spinner",false);
                }), 10000
            );
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": title,
                "type": type,
                "message": message
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
            component.set("v.spinner", false);
            //$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
            
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

The spinner you are using is controlled by the attribute "Spinner". So when you set it to false i.e component.set("v.spinner", false); then spinner stops. As per your code when you request lightningAbortEmail action if returnvalue is not equal to "Aborted", the spinner stops.
If your action returns "Aborted" then this code is used to stop spinner after 10 seconds.
`window.setTimeout( $A.getCallback(function() { component.set("v.spinner",false); }), 10000 );`

Use the above logic with appropriate delay if you want the spinner to last longer.